# Query with double nested array of elements

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am stuck at this. I'm trying to query two levels of nested documents with the index i.e [0]. Here's my mongoDb document.

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5b8803a07078906483e2e8a9"),
    "vote": [
      [
        "a4d77175-250d-4990-bc1c-d79c8175c1f0",
        "5b82e2d1b47b3513f3f25854"
      ],
      [
        "a934cf1d-ecb1-4764-b8bb-9c3c40c1128d",
        "5b82e355b47b3513f3f25858"
      ]
    ],
    "election_id": ObjectId("5b82e3cfb47b3513f3f2585a"),
    "user_id": ObjectId("5b82e2d1b47b3513f3f25854"),
    "date": "Thu Aug 30 2018 17:48:00 GMT+0300 (EAT)",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

I'm trying to get to this value "a4d77175-250d-4990-bc1c-d79c8175c1f0" inside vote. 
I tried this to no avail.

```
exports.getVotesByPosts = (req, res, next) => {
  Vote.find({'vote[0][0]': req.params.id}, (err, vote) => {
    res.json(vote);
  }).sort( { date: -1 });
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help. Regards

Comment: do you know both the vote[0][0] and vote[0][1]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need  to use [**`$elemMatch`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) query with the [**`$eq`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/) operator

```
Vote.find({
  "vote": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "$eq": "a4d77175-250d-4990-bc1c-d79c8175c1f0"
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: can we use positional character $ in that to fetch only matched array?

Comment: [**`$`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_) is the projection operator we cannot use it to query.

Comment: yeah the question is can we use projection here

Comment: sir that's my question to you

Comment: Thanks Anthony Winzlet

Comment: @mehta-rohan yes we can use `$` for projection here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how i fixed it using Anthony's answer

```
    Vote.find({
      "vote": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "$elemMatch": {
            "$eq": req.params.id
          }
        }
      }
    });
```